# Stacked highcharts on the same graph, with a new y axis each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have separate, stacked highcharts. I'd like to keep them on the same graph, but stacked on top of each other, resetting the y axis to 0 each time. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqkcqx5p/) of them all separate:

I've also attached an example graph of what I am imagining. The blue horizontal lines represent each new chart series's 0 point.

[Sample graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOQRL.jpg)

```
//random line so it will let me post the fiddle. Ignore this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve a similar effect using different `height` of multiple yAxis.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6b9prwjc/

Comment: Ah okay this is great. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are making highchart for each series in the array `seriesAll` by looping through it and that is causing it to create seperate charts for each series. If you just create 1 highchart and give it the series array, it will plot all the series on the same chart. Here is a modified version of your code to give you what your looking for.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/zdzdrW

Also please check out the docs of highcharts and it will give you all the information you need. E.g. here is the combined charts link:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types

**[Edit for stacking option]**

You can also stack them on top of each other by setting the plotOption > series > stacking properties. e.g.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

Learn more on stacking in the following doc link.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.stacking

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful! Is it possible, however, to stack the data like the example graph I posted? I'm trying to avoid the repeating x axis label and keep them all in one. Just reset the 0 point for each new piece of data

Comment: Yes. Updating answer

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much